# jQuery: from top-fixed to bottom-fixed when reaching the footer

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I need to stop a fixed sidebar when the footer is reached. I have the code below, but if you scroll down, the sidebar gets over the footer when reaching it. Of course, *it will be fixed to the top again when scrolling up*. Any help?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 210) {
      alert ("footer reached!");
      $('.sidebar').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: 210,
      })
      
   } else {
     
      $('.sidebar').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0
     })
   }
});
```

```css
.body {
   overflow: hidden;
    height: 1000px;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}


.footer {
   height: 200px;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the jQuery plug-in ScrollToFixed. It does exactly this for you. I've used it with pretty good success.

Code: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Demo page: http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

Additionally, if you find yourself using Bootstrap, they have something similar I believe called "Affix".